# Can $\frac{n!}{(n-r)!r!}$ be simplified?

Tags: algorithms, binomial-coefficients, factorial

I'm trying to calculate in a program the number of possible unique subsets of a set of unique numbers, given the subset size, using the following formula:

$\dfrac{n!}{(n-r)!r!}$

The trouble is, on the face of it, you may need an enormous structure to hold the dividend (at least).  Is there a way of simplifying this calculation, so that it can be calculated using something smaller like $64$-bit integers, or are you really going to have to store numbers like $60!$?

Alternatively, is there a formula that is more suited to computing the aforementioned value?

Comment: One helpful thing is that $\frac{n!}{(n-r)!}=(n-r+1)(n-r+2)\dots n$ and $\frac{n!}{r!}=(r+1)(r+2)\dots n$. You can save yourself some time by using one of these expressions, (and choosing which one based on which of $(n-r)$ and $r$ is bigger will also help).

Comment: This solution might be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11032879/2428123

Comment: You mentioned you are doing this in a program, what language is it? Most languages should have an optimized function for combinations in one or another of the optional libraries.

Comment: It's C#. (extra characters to get over the minimum comment size requirement)

Comment: Since its a .NET language I would suggest using the .NET library [MathNet.Numerics.Combinatorics](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics/Combinatorics.htm), the library is [freely available](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/), and the algorithms should already be optimized.

Comment: This depends heavily on what you plan to use those numbers afterwards. For example, you can store the logarithm of the number instead, sacrificing some precision. Or, you can store formulas, and reduce them only when necessary. Or, you can just store everything like you said. It does take a lot more space than a 64-bit integer, but it seems to work efficiently enough for many applications.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Multiplicative_formula

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned by others, the binomial coefficient

$$\binom{n}{r}=\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$$

is already so fundamental a quantity, that it is itself considered a canonical form. Nevertheless, you seem to be asking how one might compute this, while avoiding unsavory events like integer overflow.

Since this is for programming purposes, if you can stand to use a two-dimensional array, you might be interested in the doubly-indexed recurrence relation

$$\binom{n}{r}=\binom{n-1}{r}+\binom{n-1}{r-1}$$

along with the initial conditions $\tbinom{n}{0}=\tbinom{n}{n}=1$, or the singly-indexed recurrences

$$\begin{align*}
\binom{n}{r}&=\frac{n}{n-r}\binom{n-1}{r}\\
\binom{n}{r}&=\frac{n-r+1}{r}\binom{n}{r-1}
\end{align*}$$

One other possibility is to instead deal with the *logarithms* of the factorials, since $\log(ab)=\log\,a+\log\,b$ and $\log(a/b)=\log\,a-\log\,b$. You might want to look into *Stirling's formula* if you want to take this route, but this is only intended for the cases where $n$ and $r$ are large.

Comment: As I'm a lazy programmer :-), I actually followed user2307487's advice and used the MathNet library's `Combinatorics.Combinations` method to calculate what I needed (internally, it calls its `Binomial` function with `Binomial(totalSetSize, subsetSize)`, where the `Binomial` function returns `Math.Floor(0.5 + Math.Exp(FactorialLn(n) - FactorialLn(k) - FactorialLn(n - k)))`).  This answer is good though so I've accepted it.

Comment: Yes, that method you speak of is precisely my last proposal. Still, if you might someday find that the calls to exponentials/logarithms are too expensive for your application, you can use the recurrences as a fallback.

Answer (score 2):

It may depend on what is "simplified" for you. For example

$$\frac{n!}{(n-r)!r!}=\frac{(n-r+1)(n-r+2)\cdot\ldots\cdot n}{r!}=\frac{(r+1)(r+2)\cdot\ldots\cdot n}{(n-r)!}$$

Comment: Well, for me it means "not having to store enormous numbers to do the calculation". :-)

Comment: Well then, @Jez : you have two simplifications there up for you to choose.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the formula is nothing but
$$\frac{n\cdot(n-1)\cdot...\cdot(n-r+1)}{1\cdot2\cdot...\cdot r} $$

This allows for easy calculation for values of $\;k\;$ up to $\;50\;$ or so.

Comment: @DonAntonio indeed. ill fix that

Comment: @CBenni But $k$ isn't mentioned in your example...

Comment: Most probably it was meant to be $\,r\,$ , @Jez

Answer (score 1):

For the purposes of a computer program, it's probably best to split it up unto $r$ different factors, each of which can be held in a standard double.

First assume without loss of generality that $2r<n$.  If not, use the fact that ${n\choose r} ={n\choose n-r}$. This is obvious from the formula.

Now we have
$$\begin{array}{rl}
\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!} &= \frac{1\times2\times\dots\times n}{(1\times2\times\dots\times r)(1\times2\times\dots\times n-r)} \\&= \frac{(1\times2\times\dots\times r)(r+1\times r+2\times\dots\times n)}{(1\times2\times\dots\times r)(1\times2\times\dots\times n-r)} \\
&=\frac{r+1}{1}\times\frac{r+2}2 \times \dots\times \frac{r+(n-r)}{r}
\end{array}$$

So you may calculate the value of each fraction in a double and multiply them all quite easily.  The answer you get should be an integer; if not you're losing precision somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

To calculate $\binom{n}{r}$ with

- the least likelihood of overflow
- keeping any intermediate calculations as small as possible
- using only integers (no chance of involving even rationals),

use the following identity:

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
\binom{n}{r+1}&=&\frac{n-r}{r+1}\binom{n}{r-1}
\end{array}
$$

What this translates to is, in Pascal's triangle, moving along a row, starting from 1.

For example, to compute $$\binom{14}{4} = \frac{14\cdot13\cdot12\cdot11}{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4},$$ it is

$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
14*13&=&182\\
     &&/2&=&91\\
     &&&&\cdot12&=&1092\\
     &&&&&&/3&=&364\\
     &&&&&&&&\cdot11&=&4004\\
     &&&&&&&&&&/4&=&1001\\
\end{array}
$$

Since you're moving a long the row, you know that you'll be getting integers every time (you can always divide evenly). Also, you've computed other Pascal numbers along the way so you'll be more likely to remember them next time. What's $14 \choose 5$? Easy, multiply by $10/5$ to get $1001\cdot2$ or 2002.

This is also a manageable method for doing it in your head: easy sequence, low calculation overhead, fewer digits to remember.